# Unmarshal JSON when only half of the key is known

Tags: go

Is it possible to unmarshal JSON response when you only know half of the key name?

Example:

```
data := []byte(`[{"animal_name": "Goofy", "location": "Europe"},  {"person_name": "Gigo", "location": "Asia"}]`)
```

In this case, there are two possibilities, key name starts with some sort of an identifier (`animal`, `person`) and always ends with `_key`. There can be more (random) identifiers.

In python, you could try to retrieve the key value with `endswith` or something like that. But is possible to do so in `go`?

https://go.dev/play/p/HGQ7qFgehve.go

Comment: Either unmarshal to a type `[]map[string]string` and do post processing later - possibly transforming to a slice of interfaces of concrete types (`Animal`, `Person`, etc.) that implement a `Name` and `Location` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unmarshal the JSON to a slice of maps and then extract whatever you need from the slice:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Entry struct {
    Animalname string `json:"animal_name"`
    Location   string
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`[{"animal_name": "Goofy", "location": "Europe"},  {"person_name": "Gigo", "location": "Asia"}]`)
    // json.Unmarshal will initialize it as a slice of maps: []map[string]string.
    // Alternatively, you can set the type explicitly:
    // var entries []map[string]string
    var entries interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &entries)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(entries)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface on a slice of interfaces. Then in this custom function use some logic to determine which struct type should be used. I used [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage) to avoid full unmarshalling of the data until we know which type to use.

([playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/bDIMM5vVx-A))

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

type EntitySlice []Entity

func (es *EntitySlice) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    var objSlice []json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &objSlice)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, obj := range objSlice {
        kv := make(map[string]json.RawMessage)
        err = json.Unmarshal(obj, &kv)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var entityType string
        for k := range kv {
            i := strings.Index(k, "_name")
            if i != -1 {
                entityType = k[:i]
                break
            }
        }

        var e Entity
        switch entityType {
        case "person":
            e = &Person{}
        case "animal":
            e = &Animal{}
        }

        err = json.Unmarshal(obj, &e)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        *es = append(*es, e)
    }

    return nil
}

type Entity interface {
    EntityMarker()
}

type Person struct {
    Name     string `json:"person_name"`
    Location string
}

// Just so we implement Entity
func (p *Person) EntityMarker() {}

type Animal struct {
    Name     string `json:"animal_name"`
    Location string
}

// Just so we implement Entity
func (a *Animal) EntityMarker() {}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`[{"animal_name": "Goofy", "location": "Europe"},  {"person_name": "Gigo", "location": "Asia"}]`)

    var entitySlice EntitySlice
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &entitySlice)
    if err != nil {
        spew.Dump(err)
    }
    spew.Dump(entitySlice)
}
```

Comment: How you are using `json.RawMessage` here is very brittle. Firstly in the sample JSON there's 2 lead bytes `{"` which you are not accounting for - so it should be `entityType = k[2:i]`. But even this is not enough as the key order is not guaranteed i.e. location could be first. Index scanning for `_name` is asking for trouble if that pattern is in not just a key but also a *value*.

Comment: @colm.anseo `k` is not the raw json, it is the actual key so `animal_name`, `location`, `person_name`, `location`: https://goplay.tools/snippet/k9TRXp5sV8K. I agree that using a suffix on a key for matching is not ideal, but it is literally the use case OP presents, I would personally go with a `"type": "aninal"` key and then use that in combination with json.RawMessage to decode further just like the official example: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-RawMessage-Unmarshal

Comment: In your original version when the name did not unmarshal - I had assumed it was a parsing issue.  And yes, an input type indicator would make things easier, as `RawMessage` is ideal for that delayed unmarshaling use case.